# Bootstrap datetimepicker for the id of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the date picker working when I set the id for the input tag like the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDate" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#inputDate').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I just wonder why its not working if I used the div instead of the input tag ( the datepicker id), as I saw some examples online using the div instead of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work if you don't set class `input-group` on `<div>`

Check it here https://jsfiddle.net/a9729dc9/

Answer (score 1):

`.datetimepicker();` init the input that will use the datepicker feature, that why we should call it on the concerned `input` field.

If you want to reference to the `input` through the `div` you could use it as :

```
$('#datepicker input').datetimepicker();
//Or also
$('#datepicker #inputDate').datetimepicker();
```

In bootstrap you have to add class `.input-group` to the parent (container) `div` so bootstrap could detect `input-group-addon` and init the picker, e.g :

```
<div class="input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but look at this site  
:https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

here he used the class of div :
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
    </div>
</div>


$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d'
});

Comment: also this website is more clear :
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/